# Guide to Customizing Ubuntu VM

Tags: customization, virtualization

I am running a Ubuntu (12.04) vm using VM Player. 
My question is a two parter.

1) Is it possible for me to customize the vm so that I only get a terminal and gui support. (will sometimes use Nautilus, Firefox or Chrome, and some Tkinter built apps)

2) Can anyone reccomend a guide for doing this? I've been using Ubuntu for about 2 years and am pretty comfortable with it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI, the fact that it's a VM has no bearing.

Comment: Yes I know, just trying to be accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

- What you want to do is set your Ubuntu machine to boot to run level 3 (this will boot you in console only login mode with networking)
- Then you will need to config your X server
- Edit openSSH server to support X11 forwarding
- SSH into your server with the -X option added this supports X application forwarding ( ssh root@x.x.x.x -X )
- Then find your application you want to launch and execute it from /usr/bin or wherever it is.
- Then your application should launch providing its configured correctly.

You will need to use a Linux or *nix based machine though to support the X forwarding. Well at least I think so. Don't know it if its supported on windows.

Something like [this](http://www.linux-tip.net/cms/content/view/302/26/) should help you I think.

Hope it helps.

Bill

***EDIT1:Putty supports X11 forwarding didn't know this quite nice to know. Windows will be find to ssh through with then.***